# User defined exception - python

Tags: python-2.7

I am learning how to create userdefined exception in python

```
import sqlite3 

class MyError(Exception):
     def __init__(self, value):
     self.value = value
try:         
    conn= sqlite34.connect('database56.sqlite')
    print conn 
    print 'connection established'
except MyError as e:
    print 'Error message:', e.value
```

When I run the above program ,I get the name error
NameError: name 'sqlite13' is not defined

how do I call the user defined exception if there is a failure to connect to the database ?  When  [except MyError as e:] is replaced by [except:],still the exception block is not called.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: The code here says nothing about sqlite13, only sqlite34, so the error your referencing isn't in reference to the code you've posted.

Comment: Are you sure about that last claim? If you use a naked `except:` in the code above, it will catch the `NameError`.

Comment: plain except: worked..thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining an exception doesn't change what exceptions are raised by other modules. If you want your code to use your exception, you have to catch what the other module rasies and then re-raise your own.

```
import sqlite3 

class MyError(Exception):
     def __init__(self, value):
     self.value = value
try:         
    conn= sqlite3.connect('database56.sqlite')
    print conn 
    print 'connection established'
except sqlite3.Error as e:
    print 'Error message:', e.value
    raise MyError('Could not connect to db: ' + e.value)
```

I've caught the generic sqlite3 error here but you may need to add other exceptions if they are also raised by the module. Exactly what those exceptions are isn't easy to figure out in python. You can read the source, experiment or look around at examples on the net.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

In this case, you want to catch a NameError, so you should directly use that in the except statement. If you want to perform actions after catching the error, you should put that actions in the except statement. Some documentation can be found [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/exception-handling). 
Example:

```
except NameError as e:
    print 'Error message:', e.value
    print 'Splite module not loaded'
```

User-defined errors are for example useful with wrong/unexpected parameters or output. So user-defined errors are useful because you determine the situations when they are raised, which is not necessarily a situation where "python would crash".

[Here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/user-defined-exception) some documentation about it.

Maybe an example can help clarifying.

Say you have a function when one of the variables is the price of something.
Then you might do:

```
class NegativePriceException(Exception):

    def __init__(self):
        print "Price can't be negative!"
        raise AttributeError

def calc_price(...):
    price = ...  #some calculation
    if price < 0:
        raise NegativePriceException
    return price
```

Comment: Thank you..got it